# Having problems editing text files in java

Tags: java

Hey there somy code below is supposed to do one thing its hard to explain but i will try
for example this is the content of my txt file

```
atif12,123,0
kamran11,134,0
abh3,123,0
```

now if my username is `kamran 11` and password is `134` which I entered so this program should turn the 0 to 500 and keep the rest as it is but my file gets updated and only shows this

```
kamran11,134,500
```

thus all is deleted and I don't know where I went wrong can someone correct me, please?

```
         File file = new File("customer.txt");//this is the txtfile
                        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

                        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
                            while (in.hasNext()) {
                                lines.add(in.nextLine());
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException eo) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
                        }

                        String comp=username+","+pass;

                        try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file)) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { //iterate over lines
                                String comp2=lines.get(i);
                                System.out.println(comp2);
                                if(comp2.contains(comp)){
                                String[] parts = lines.get(i).split(","); //split line by commas

                                for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) { //iterate over parts
                                    if (j == 2) { //if I hit the first element in this line that is a zero
                                        int temp = Integer.parseInt(parts[j]);
                                        temp = temp + 500;
                                        parts[j] = Integer.toString(temp);
                                        break; //break out of the loop
                                    }
                                }

                                for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) { //iterate over all the parts and write them back
                                     System.out.println("this work");
                                    out.write(parts[j]);

                                    if (j < parts.length - 1) { //only add a comma if it isn't at the end of the line
                                        out.write(',');
                                    }
                                }

                                if (i < lines.size() - 1) { //add a line break if it isn't the last line
                                    System.out.println("this work1");
                                    out.write('\n');
                                }
                                //break;
                            }
                                else{
                                    System.out.println("this dont work");
                                }

                        }

                            out.flush(); //write everything to the file
                        } catch (IOException ep) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("IO exception occurred");
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106657/editing-part-of-a-string-that-is-separated-by-a-in-a-txt-files-in-java/62107488?noredirect=1#comment109933576_62107488), and the information provided in this question, I believe you want the following:

```
File file = new File("customer.txt");
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String user = sc.nextLine(); //ask user for the username
String pwd = sc.nextLine(); //ask user for the password

try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (in.hasNext()) { //read in all lines
        lines.add(in.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
}

try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { //iterate over lines
        String[] parts = lines.get(i).split(","); //split line by commas

        if (parts[0].equals(user) && parts[1].equals(pwd)) { //if username and password match first and second parts of line, respectively
            parts[2] = "500"; //set third part of line to 500
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) { //iterate over all the parts and write them back
            out.write(parts[j]);

            if (j < parts.length - 1) { //only add a comma if it isn't at the end of the line
                out.write(',');
            }
        }

        if (i < lines.size() - 1) { //add a line break if it isn't the last line
            out.write('\n');
        }
    }

    out.flush(); //write everything to the file
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("IO exception occurred");
}
```